# express subdomain handler routes get mixed up

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I'm trying to get my subdomains working with each a diffrent router in express but they get mixed up.

when i'm going to panel.localhost:3333/login i see the login page. But whenever i'm going to api.localhost:3333/login i get the same page... and i did not defined the login route in de api router. So is there anyone who know how to solve this? :)

```
import { renderer, listen, sessionConfiguration } from './server.express';
import { _static, scripts, modules, staticPages } from './server.static';
import { serverRegisterAPIs } from './server.apis';
import serverConfiguration from './server.configuration';

let express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    routerPanel = express.Router(),
    routerApi = express.Router();

serverConfiguration(app).then(function(configuration) {

    mongoose.connect(process.configuration.mongo.url);

    app.use( require('express-subdomain-handler')({ baseUrl: 'localhost', prefix: 'subdomain', logger: true }) );

    // configure the session to ....
    sessionConfiguration(app);
    // configure the renderer
    renderer(app);

    // hook up a few static calls to the server
    _static(routerPanel, express);
    scripts(routerPanel, express);
    modules(routerPanel, express);
    // register static files
    staticPages(routerPanel);

    // register api
    //serverRegisterAPIs(routerApi);


    routerApi.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        console.log("test");
    });
    //set subdomains
    app.use('/subdomain/:panel',routerPanel);
    app.use('/subdomain/:api', routerApi);

    // start listening
    listen(app);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I set the subdomain I've added a `:` to the route so that its parameter `express` will parse. So instead I removed the `:` and now it's working!

Comment: @Pardeep This posted answer is OP's solution to the problem.